# Docker+Python: can't receive a response from a simple request

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, python-requests

I am trying to create a simple dockerized python-application to fetch some data from an API.

Now I came along the problem that even the simplest approach to do a request doesn't work used with `docker-compose up`. I always get a `requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout`.

If I do it without docker, there occurrs no problem - everything works as expected.

`app.py`

```
import requests
def main():
    url = 'https://google.com'
    print("Hello.")
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=2)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.text
        print("Received something")
        print(data)
    else:
        print('Failure.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5040:5040
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

`requirements.txt`

```
requests==2.22.0
```

Does anyone else experienced this type of behaviour? Thanks for sharing your solutions.

Comment: Can you please share the proper log? Either you get this from the python `request` api or docker network?  For me when I run your code it is running fine without any issue.

Comment: Thanks for trying out... If I change the `docker-compose.yml` in a way where I remove the `networks ...` and add `network_mode: host` then it is running for me on my machine...